# Cosa sono le "schiavenze"?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *La malora*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> Era contenta anche lei, e adesso sarei stato una vera bestia se mi mettevo a cabalizzare sul motivo della sua contentezza. Le dissi adagio: – Ci sono delle **schiavenze** in giro da prendere.

Sapreste spiegarmi cos'è una "schiavenza"? Non ho trovato questo vocabolo in nessun dizionario. Si tratta di un termine di origine piemontese?

Comment: Cercando su Google _schiavenze_ (e non _schiavenza_) ho trovato questo: https://www.dizionario-italiano.it/dizionario-italiano.php?lemma=SCHIAVENZA100

Comment: Grazie, @Vincenzo: cercando "schiavanderia" ho trovato [questo documento](https://ebiblio.istat.it/digibib/Annali/TO00003841_Serie02Vol08ed1879.pdf) con un'interessante spiegazione alla pagina 130.

Comment: Splendido! (comunque, mi raccomando, è Vi**n**cenzo )

Comment: @VincenzoOliva: Ho corretto il mio commento precedente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nel documento [CARATTERI ECONOMICO-AGRARI DEI COMPARTIMENTI - FIGURE - POSIZIONI
E VOCI PROFESSIONALI AGRICOLE](https://ebiblio.istat.it/digibib/censpop1936/IST0005816Caratteri_economicoagrari_dei_compartimenti_FigurePosizionievociprofessionaliagricole/IST0005816cp1936caratterieconomicoagrari+OCRottimizzato.pdf) redatto da ISTITUTO CENTRALE DI STATISTICA DEL REGNO D'ITALIA - VIII CENSIMENTO GENERALE DELLA POPOLAZIONE
21 APRILE 1936~XIV  ho trovato:

> Nelle province di Cuneo e di Torino, non sono rari i contratti di
>   quasi-affitto, nell'Alessandrino è frequente ***la schiavenza a
>   compartecipazione***, nella pianura di Saluzzo la boaria a dar tutto e
>   a paghe.

Inoltre vengono elencate le principali figure agricole specifiche nelle varie province piemontesi.

È quindi una sorta di contratto agricolo con per cui coltivando una porzione di terreno vengono dati in cambio denaro ed anche beni alimentari.

Come fatto notare da @VincenzoOliva su un dizionario italiano per [schiavenze](https://www.dizionario-italiano.it/dizionario-italiano.php?lemma=SCHIAVENZA100):

> 1 *storia* variante meno comune di schiavanderia
>
> 2 *storia* podere affidato a uno *schiavandaro*

dove per [schiavandaro](https://www.dizionario-italiano.it/dizionario-italiano.php?parola=schiavandaro) si intende:

> nel passato, coltivatore di un fondo alle dirette dipendenze di un
>   proprietario, dal quale riceveva in cambio l'abitazione e una
>   remunerazione in denaro o in natura

Più avanti nel testo si trova un passaggio in cui lo stesso protagonista cercava informazioni su questa particolare modalità di contratto:

> Pensavo solo per me e Fede, e appena avevo un’ora libera correvo
>   all’osteria di Manera dove c’era sempre un certo traffico di gente e
>   cercavo di sapere il più possibile sulle ***schiavenze***; n’avrò sentiti
>   una dozzina, i più pratici, e tutti mi dissero la stessa cosa: per un
>   anno davano cento lire, un quintale di meliga e una brenta di vino. Un
>   affare come i galeotti, ma niente mi spaventava e non avrei fatto
>   smorfie neanche per il posto, al momento buono avrei accettato magari
>   una schiavenza sotto le rocche di Cissone.